# Is the convolution integration zero?

Tags: integration, convolution, fourier-transform

$$F(\omega)=\frac{\sin \omega}{\omega}$$
$$G(\omega)=\frac{\sin \omega}{\omega}e^{-j2\omega}$$

\begin{align}
F(\omega )*G(\omega)&=\int^{+ \infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\sin \tau}{\tau}\frac{\sin (\omega-\tau)}{(\omega-\tau)}e^{-j2(\omega-\tau)}d\tau \\
&=0?
\end{align}

$F(\omega)$ and $G(w)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.

[$f(t)$ and $g(t)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZnnu.jpg)

Comment: What you have written is not the convolution of $F$ and $G$.

Comment: it should be. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: The correct convolution is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(\tau)}{\tau} \frac{\sin(\omega-\tau)}{\omega-\tau} e^{-j2\tau} d \tau$. You can also reverse a few things, but the sines and the denominators can't be the same.

Comment: Still have no idea how to do this. $F(\omega)$ and $G(\omega)$ are the Fourier transform of two non-overlap rectangular pulse signals. I just can't prove it's zero.

Comment: for answering this, you'll need to go to the (inverse) Fourier domain, where the convolution becomes a product,  and $\frac{\sin \omega}{\omega}$ becomes much simpler ($1_{|t| < 1}$)

Comment: The signal $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is attached as a picture in the post.  the multiplied product $f(t)g(t)$ is zero. so the convolution should also be zero. just want to figure it out and verify convolution is zero.

Comment: $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are the inverse Fourier transform of $F(\omega)$ and $G(\omega)$.